# Self referential class

Tags: c#, class, pointers

Trying to write a class for a directory which can have a parent and a list of children.

Class definition:

```
class Directory {
    public string name;
    public Directory parentDir;
    public List<Directory> subDirs;

    public Directory(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addSubDir(Directory x) {
        subDirs.Add(x);
    }
}
```

Sample code trying to create two instances and set one as a child of the other:

```
Directory temp1 = new Directory("root");

Directory temp2 = new Directory("games");

temp1.addSubDir(temp2);
```

The error I get is:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: forget to initialize subDirs .  `public List<Directory> subDirs = new List<Directory>();` :)

Comment: Please explain how these questions are duplicates. I'm asking what I was doing wrong with having a class contain a member that is a pointer to its same type. And the problem was that I wasn't initializing that member. The other question is much more abstract and wouldn't come up in a search for my specific problem at all. They are so far removed I can't tell if this is just a joke or a troll.

Comment: Basically I'm asking for a solution to problem X, which gives error Y. And the other question is about error Y. There are many problems that could result in error Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never instantiated this

```
public List<Directory> subDirs;
```

Change it to this:

```
public List<Directory> subDirs = new List<Directory>();
```

Since you put it in your title, I thought I would comment.  Your error doesn't have anything to do with being a self referential class (it's perfectly fine to do that).  If it was an error with being able to do that, you would get a compile time error and not a run time one.

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I see. Would it be better form to instantiate the subDirs list in the constructor?

Comment: You can do it either way.  It all depends on you different usage scenarios.  I would probably leave it the way it is, because that way if you choose to have multiple constructors, you always know it's automatically created.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks again